# Dropping last N characters in var in KSH

Tags: ksh

I have a var="31 Dec 2015 (return status=0)" in a shell script.
How do I change the value of var to var=31 Dec 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [parameter substitution](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html#Parameter%20Substitution). Any one of:

```
var="31 Dec 2015 (return status=0)"

# remove a specific number of characters
var=${var%??????????????????}; echo "$var"

# remove a string with 2 spaces
var=${var% * *}; echo "$var"

# remove a string beginning with " ("
var=${var% \(*}; echo "$var"
```